# Kotlin cast one AppCompatActivity into another one in Android

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-storage

world! I am new to Android development. I am creating an app and I have a question, how can I cast one AppCompatActvity class into another?

This is my sample code:

```
    class UploadActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    var sm = FirebaseStorageManager()

    private var filePath: Uri? = null

    private val btnSelectImage: AppCompatButton by lazy {
        findViewById(R.id.select)
    }

    private val btnUploadImage: AppCompatButton by lazy {
        findViewById(R.id.upload)
    }

    private val imgPost: AppCompatImageView by lazy {
        findViewById(R.id.imageView)
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_upload)
        init()
    }

    private fun init() {
        btnSelectImage.setOnClickListener {
            imagePicker()
        }

        btnUploadImage.setOnClickListener {
            filePath?.let {
                it1 -> sm.uploadImage(this, it1)
                thread {
                    Thread.sleep(1000)
                    //ParseUploadActivity().uploader(this, it1)
                    //(this@UploadActivity as ParseUploadActivity).uploader(this, it1)
                    (this as ParseUploadActivity).uploader(this, it1)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private fun imagePicker() {
        val intent = Intent()
        intent.type = "image/*"
        intent.action = Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), 1)
    }

    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        if(requestCode == 1 && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            if(data == null || data.data == null) {
                return
            }
            filePath = data.data
            try {
                val bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(contentResolver, filePath)
                imgPost?.setImageBitmap(bitmap)
            } catch(e: IOException) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {
        var inflater: MenuInflater = menuInflater
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.filemenu, menu)
        return true
    }

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        return when(item.itemId) {
            R.id.upload_menu -> {
                true
            }
            R.id.show_menu -> {
                true
            }
            else -> super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is in this line of code `(this as ParseUploadActivity).uploader(this, it1)`. I tried different ways but still have an error and can't fix it.

P.S.
ParseUploadActivity is also inherited from AppCompatActivity.
I mean

`class ParseUploadActivity : AppCompatActivity() {...}`

Comment: You can't. `ParseUploadActivity` is not in the type hierarchy of `UploadActivity`, so `(this as ParseUploadActivity)` will always fail.

Comment: @BenP. how can I resolve it or call a method from this class?

Comment: @totta you can't. You can either copy the code in the `uploader()` function in to the current class or extract it to a separate class where it can be used by both activities. If it was me I would choose the second option

Comment: @IvanWooll ok, got it, thanks

Comment: Can you please tell us how is this question related to Firebase?